# Creating an operator-priority based dictionary in python

Tags: python, stack, operators

I'm a python beginner, and I've studied lately data structures in Python, namely, lists, tuples, dictionaries, all that jazz. Now, as a little learning excercise, I'd like to write an infix-to-postfix converter using the Shunting Yard Algorithm. Now, I've written this program before in C, and there, to get the operator priority, I only defined a function that returned the priority of the token using a switch statement. Here, I'm at a loss, because switch statements don't exist. The ugly solution would be to do the same, but with elif statements, that's my last resort, but, is there a more elegant solution using dictionaries?

For now, my dictionary looks like this:

`priorities = {1: ('+', '-'), 2: ('*', '/'), 3: '^'}`

As you can see, multiple operators have the same priority, my question is, how can I know the priority of any given token using this structure? If my token is '^' that's easy, just priorities['^'], but if it's any other operator? How can I associate them with the tuple that contains it? something like priorities['+']?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not invert the dictionary?

```
{'^': 3, '*': 2, '/': 2, '+':1, '-':1}
```